# apt-get autoremove --purge -y seems to be stuck

Tags: linux, apt, dpkg, lock

I'm not entirely sure why this is happening, so it seemed wise to ask here before I interfere with it.

I'm attempting to install nasm, but I get the message:

```
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 15429 (apt-get)...
```

Ad infinitum. My first thought was that package manager might be updating, but that doesn't seem to be the case. A quick `ps aux | grep -i apt` has two entries right at the top:

```
root       15428  0.0  0.0  16204  3748 ?        S    May23   0:00 systemd-inhibit --why=Performing autoremoval --who=Update Manager --what=shutdown --mode=block /usr/bin/apt-get autoremove --purge -y
root       15429  0.0  0.4  92880 77328 ?        S    May23   0:20 /usr/bin/apt-get autoremove --purge -y
```

This implies that it may have been triggered by a shutdown, but what it does not tell me is why it's taking so incredibly long to complete.

Is it at all safe to kill that specific process? I'm usually pretty hesitant to interfere with package management. Should I wait? Would an idiot-reboot be safer?

If context is necessary, I'm using a *heavily customized* build of Linux Mint 20.3; though I've done nothing to the kernel itself. There's no update check (or update) happening, and the only things I've got running are a terminal, Chrome, and the XFCE desktop environment.

Thanks to anyone who can give me a handle on why this might be happening and how I get past it.

Comment: Tracing the process `ltrace -p 15429` may give you a clue on what the command is waiting for (it is in the `S`leeping state).

Comment: Good idea, but nothing's printing out. I ran it under sudo as it isn't apparently from my process; but I just get a blank line like it's expecting more input.

Comment: At this point I'm guessing that I could just reboot; but I'm now *academically* curious where this is coming from!

Comment: I'd try reboot first. If any packages stay mid-upgrade you can always remove & install them again

Comment: Do you have any cron job to clean unused packages? (apt-get autoremove..)

Comment: @BrahimGaabab I wasn't aware of one, but this appears to have been initiated after a shutdown. That implies that there may have been a pre-packaged cron job, or equivalent, that I just wasn't aware of. I did install a new kernel recently and Mint has a policy of only keeping the current and last kernels, unless the user says otherwise; so it could be that. l I'll attempt a reboot at this point, just to keep things clean.

Comment: I attempted a reboot, only to find that the ever-friendly GUI tools were also graying out shut down and reboot options. That exacerbates things. I dropped to terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F2) and `sudo shutdown -r now`, and it restarted without event, but required `sudo apt --configure -a` to run apt again. After that, NASM installed, and there have been no further incidents—I'm actually wondering if the whole thing might have just been a hardware or network hiccup.

Comment: Run `ps fax`, check its children, kill them.